# YT Analytics API: Limit of 25 rows in resultset

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I manage a YouTube MCC account for a social media agency that promotes YouTube videos. We have developed an app which fetches view data for videos we promote using the YouTube Analytics API. We've just encountered an interesting issue on a recent video we promoted, due to its popularity.

We use the Playback location detail report to get the view numbers and the sources of these views. We are only interested in fetching a subset of the domains (which is the insightPlaybackLocationDetail dimension), since there may be many sites a video was embedded on, however only some are managed by us.

The problem is (as the documentation clearly states), that there is a limit of 25 rows in the resultset with no additional filtering options.

Sometimes it occurs that the domains we are interested in are not in the top 25 domains that are returned and therefore are not returned in the resultset which, from our point, is the same as if there were no views from that domains at all.

In short, the 25 row limit means that we cannot fetch the data we need on very popular videos and where some of our managed domains are not in these top 25.

Is there any way to get around this limit or make it higher? If not, is there another way to get the data we need (that is number of embedded views per site for a given video)?

Really appreciate your help!